# How to get minecraft path with Fabric

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I have a mod that wants to read a file `splits.yml` in the minecraft directory where the other configs are (config.txt, etc.). I have no idea how I would do that. My first idea was using a Mixin

```java
@Mixin(GameOptions.class)
public class GameOptionsMixin {
    @Shadow @Final private File optionsFile;

    @Inject(method = "load", at = @At("RETURN"))
    private void load(CallbackInfo info) {
        File splits = new File(optionsFile.getParent(), "splits.yml");    
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how I would extract the value. I also cannot trust that the folder will be `.minecraft` as a lot of fabric users use MultiMC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out now.

You can use `FabricLoader.getInstance().getConfigDir()` to get the directory as a `Path` and `FabricLoader.getInstance().getConfigDir().resolve("splits.yml")` to get the File i need. Hope this helps anyone in the future